Android Studio: Video longer than screen - unable to scroll down?
I have an app that contains a video on loop which is longer than the length of the screen, however it is not possible to scroll down and see the bottom section of the video (located outside the bottom end of the screen).
How can I allow the video to be scrolled up and down?
activity_main.xml:
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/dig_lic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="2950px" />
</LinearLayout>

MainActivity.kt:
class MainActivity: ComponentActivity() {
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle ? ) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val videoView = findViewById < VideoView > (R.id.dig_lic)
    val packageName = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.dig_lic_video
    val uri = Uri.parse(packageName)
    videoView.setOnPreparedListener {
      it.isLooping = true
    }
    videoView.setVideoURI(uri)
    videoView.start()
  }
}


You are facing this issue is because you have set static height for video view i.e 2950 px. This makes your video view stretched and adding scrollview to if makes it scrollable.
1. Scrollview Example
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/dig_lic"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>

If that doesn't fixes your problem place your VideoView in a ScrollView control.
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/dig_lic"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>

Or use a WebView when the format of the video allows it.
2. Webview Example
Layout (activity_main.xml):
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/web_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>

Activity (MainActivity.kt):
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val webView = findViewById<WebView>(R.id.web_view)

        // Load a website using URL
        val url = "your video url .com "
        webView.loadUrl(url)

        // Alternatively, load HTML content from a string
        // val htmlString = "<h1>Hello from a String!</h1>"
        // webView.loadData(htmlString, "text/html", "UTF-8")

        // Enable JavaScript (optional, but recommended for many websites)
        webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    }
}


Hi @Bob Smith, thank you for taking the time to reply.

I have set the fixed layout height for my VideoView because I require the video to remain in its original ratio and it must extend beyond the length of the display and be scrollable.
When I set both heigh and width to wrap_content - as expected the long video then becomes smaller and fits into the display
When I place the VV inside a ScrollView - I am just getting an empty screen and the VV is not visible

Webview will not be suitable a it will not be possible for the video to be hosted as it contains sensitive content

I am going to test ScrollView again and this time will have the height of both the ScrollView and VideoView hardcoded to 2950px - fingers crossed that will work!

Final solution - adding additional linerlayout inside scrollview:






